# access outside project folder with Asp.net core application on linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm having some issues trying to access a folder outside the application root folder with an asp.net application deployed on Linux.

The applcation is deployed at the moment (for testing purposes) in `/home/pbl/projects/pbl-web/`.

I want to access a folder of an external hard drive I've mounted on the system, and it's located in `/mnt/ExtDist/Data`.

I'm using a PhysicalFileProvider with the following path:  `/mnt/ExtDist/Data`. This path is configured in `app.settings.json` file  and retrieved through the `IConfiguration configuration` variable.

Here's a part of the code in the `Startup.cs` file :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...

var imagePath = configuration.GetSection("PhotoManagementSettings")["ImagesFolderPath"];
var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

this.imagePhysicalFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(imagePath));
```

I've tried in different ways with no luck so far:

1. passing the absolute path
2. passing the relative path and combining with the rootPath variable (see the code above).

The `PhysicalFileProvider` is getting me the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /mnt/ExtDist/Data/
```

Testing the code in windows and giving it an absolute path like i.e "C:\Test" works fine.

So there's something weird in linux that is failing, but I cannot understand why. Any clues ?

Thanks in advance
Paolo

Comment: Not that familiar with .NET on Linux, but assuming ASP.NET is running under some user profile, does that user have (at least) read permission on that path?

Comment: the folder has rx permission (read and execute), the owner of the folder is different, the application is executed by 'pbl' user and the folder owner is 'www-data'

Comment: Funny enough, i hit this same issue today. Not got to the bottom of it, but it seems like from the web apps point of view. It can't see files outside of its defined app directly, which is the deployment location of the app (i.e. bin folder)